# Jquery Swipe detection on object for Android mobile site

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, swipe

Can anyone please point me in the direction of a decent Jquery library that can detect swipes actions on a object via jquery?

Cheers

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this script as reference for my own touch library (I wanted more functionality and to increase my mobile experience): http://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library

Of course, there is also [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) which has a long list of [touch/swipe/gesture events](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html).

Comment: Cheers for your help Tim, got it to work via jquery mobile gestures eventually.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.queness.com/post/11755/11-multi-touch-and-touch-events-javascript-libraries) is a complete list of Javascript/JQuery libraries that can handle touch events (including swipe and multi-finger swipe)